# rails application error (assests)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am encountering an error, undefined method `assests'

Web application could not be started

```
undefined method `assests' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x000000035c8f70> (NoMethodError)
  /home/vakad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing'
  /var/www/html/ucsfihglims/config/application.rb:65:in `<class:Application>'
  /var/www/html/ucsfihglims/config/application.rb:13:in `<module:SeqLIMS>'
  /var/www/html/ucsfihglims/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/www/html/ucsfihglims/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
  /var/www/html/ucsfihglims/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /home/vakad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
  /home/vakad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /home/vakad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/passenger-5.0.26/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `eval'
  /home/vakad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/passenger-5.0.26/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `preload_app'
  /home/vakad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/passenger-5.0.26/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /home/vakad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/passenger-5.0.26/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /home/vakad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/passenger-5.0.26/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
Error ID
09a5af91
```

Comment: I haven't changed anything since the last time. All of a sudden I see this error message when I try to login to the application

Comment: are you sure you haven't accidentally renamed your `assets` folder to `assests`? Just looking at the first line of your error message gives me that impression. Either that, or somewhere you are incorrectly referring to that folder as `assests`

Comment: Here is my application.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

find for the keyword `assests` in your project folder and replace with `assets`.